# SPI communication between Arduino Nano and ATTiny24

Tags: arduino, spi, attiny

I'm trying to make communication between Arduino Nano and ATTiny24 using SPI. I've written code for master(Nano) and slave(ATTiny24)(with great difficulty)  but no luck getting the proper output. I'm transmitting '1' on both sides for simplicity. Here's the code:
Master code (nano):

```
#include<SPI.h>
#define SSpin 10
void setup (void)

{
  Serial.begin(9600);                                 
 
  SPI.begin();                           
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV16);
  digitalWrite(SSpin,HIGH);                 
}

void loop(void)
{
  byte m_send,m_receive;         
  digitalWrite(SSpin, LOW);
  m_send=1;                                       
  m_receive=SPI.transfer(m_send);
  Serial.println(m_receive);     //should print 1 here but it prints 255 always
  delay(1000);
}
```

Slave(ATTiny24)

```
int data;
void setup()
{
  DDRB=(1<<PA5)|(0<<PA6)|(0<<PA4);
  USICR = (1<<USIWM0)|(1<<USICS1);
}

void loop()
{
  data=slaveSPITransfer(1);
  if(data==1)
  {
    digitalWrite(PA1,HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(PA1,LOW);
  }
}

uint8_t slaveSPITransfer(uint8_t val)
{
  USIDR = val;
  USISR = (1<<USIOIF);
  while (! (USISR & (1<<USIOIF)));
  return USIDR;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: SPI is a very simple protocol, so my advice would be to bit-bang it on both sides to get started rather than using libraries and the SPI hardware. This way you will know exactly what is happening. It might take 10 mins to write the bit-bang code, but will potentially save hours of debugging this stuff. Once you have that working, you can then try replacing the one side with library/hardware - it will be much easier when you have a known good system on the other side.

Comment: @bigjosh even though the protocol is simple, I'd not bother implementing bitbanging on hardware that actually supports SPI. He should better understand SPI

Comment: @kzkhan98, you should learn how SPI works (view some example sketches). One problem is, that you need to set SS back to high, you can't leave the slave selected for ever. The slave *needs* to get an event when selected, so whatever data is required can be placed in the output register. On the other side, the slave can't just send in a loop. It has to wait for the "oh, I got selected"-event, that's when data has to be written to the output register. The hardware will then shift over the data to the master by itself. That would require some interrupt handling on the slave side...

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a ton of products that use Atmel products. I highly highly recommend the application notes that Atmel puts out. They are high quality and typically give you some solid examples you can adapt to your application. This is the one for SPI but there are many like it for other peripherals: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/TB3215-Getting-Started-with-SPI-90003215A.pdf

Usually when you have difficulty like you described, it's because you have an issue with register settings, pin mux's or clock settings. The examples are usually rock solid and give you insight into the correct sequencing for setting up all the peripherals.